# How to print german diacritic characters in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, encoding, character, diacritics

Working on a german words (sometimes containing Umlaut characters) in an Excel2007 spreadsheet (I use xlrd xlwt and openpyxl), I get the following value:

```
var = str(ws.cell(row=i+k,column=0).value).encode('latin-1')
```

I get with print(var):

```
'[a word')
```

until coming on a word containing Umlaut characters, when I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cristina\Documents\horia\Linguistics3\px t3.py", line 68, in <module>
    var = str(ws4.cell(row=i+k,column=0).value).encode('latin-1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xdf' in position 3:ordinal not in range(128)
```

And the program stops.

If I define var as:

```
var = u'str(ws4.cell(row=i+k,column=0).value)'.encode('latin-1')
```

I get, when hen trying to print(var), I get:

```
var=str(ws.cell(row=i+k,column=0).value)
```

The program runs normally until the end

I can get the value of var in Python Shell, but not by "print(var)" in the program.

Can anybody give me a solution?

Comment: Try using .encode('utf-8'), or .encode('latin1', 'ignore')...

Comment: `print ws4.cell(row=i+k,column=0).value.encode('latin-1')` maybe?

Comment: @Hedde, no that's not a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

First of all, read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html (seriously)

Then, understand that Python2 has two distinct data-types:
unicode, for "agnostic" handing all possible characters, but which can nt be used in
input/output, such as "print" or writing to files, without being *encoded*  into the
other data type: strings.

Strings are encoding-dependent.

What I am almost sure is going on there, given your error message, is that the `ws4.cell(row=i+k,column=0).value` call is returning you a unicode value. (I can't test it on my non-windows environment here) - to be sure instead of guess work, you may want to run things there once with 
`print (type(ws4.cell(row=i+k,column=0).value)` just to assert you are getting unicode values.

Thus, when you do `str(ws4.(...).value)` you are telling Python to just convert unicode to str without any encoding - that is the call that raises your error, not the subsequent "decode" call.

If that is what is going on, simply replace that `str` call for `unicode`:

```
var = u'str(ws4.cell(row=i+k,column=0).value)'.encode('latin-1')
```

That should fix your problem. I hope you've read the article I linked above - it **is** helpful.

Also, mark your Python source code with the corresponding encoding you are using - otherwise
you will get an error on any non-ASCII char in your source code.

For example, write this on the very first line of your code:

```
# coding: latin1
```

(Although for any serious project you should be using utf-8 instead.)